# Spring & JUnit Transaction: transaction cleanup in @after method causing partial commit

Tags: java, spring, junit, transactions

So I'm working on a JUnit test case for my database connection. Because my tables auto-increment their keys, I'm trying to reset the auto-increment after the tests so that I don't end up using extra values by running tons of tests.

I'm using Spring transactions with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, which causes the transactions to automatically roll back upon completion, which is great. A problem happens when I try and do the auto-increment reset, though.

So, here's one of my test cases from the class:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testStudentOperations(){
    Student student = new Student();
    setStudent1(student);
    studentDao.insertStudent(student);
    int studentId = student.getStudentId();

    student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
    assertNotNull(INSERT_FAIL, student);
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getFirstName(), "First");
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getLastName(), "Last");
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getBirthDate(), LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1));
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getGender(), 'U');
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getGrade(), 1);

    setStudent2(student);
    studentDao.updateStudent(student);

    student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
    assertNotNull(UPDATE_FAIL, student);
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getFirstName(), "First2");
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getLastName(), "Last2");
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getBirthDate(), LocalDate.of(1950, 1, 1));
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getGender(), 'M');
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getGrade(), 2);

    studentDao.deleteStudent(student);

    student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
    assertNull(DELETE_FAIL, student);
}
```

Creates the entity, tests insert/update/delete/get operations, nice and simple. This, on its own, works perfectly. The tests are all run, and the transaction gets completely rolled back at the end so no dummy data ends up in my database. Nice and clean.

However, if I add this @After method, everything gets screwy:

```
@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@After
public void after(){
    System.out.println("Running");
    if(studentDao instanceof HibernateStudentDao){
        System.out.println("Correct Dao");
        ((HibernateStudentDao) studentDao).resetAutoIncrement();
    }
    else{
        throw new RuntimeException("Auto-Increment not reset");
    }
}
```

So this method is to run after the test cases and reset the auto-increment of the tables. The auto-increment reset SQL code works perfectly (I'll paste that code at the end). The problem is that when this runs, the test case ends up partially committing. The first set of values ("First", "Last", etc) gets committed to the database, while the second set ("First2, "Last2", etc) gets rolled back.

I don't know what's going on. I think it has something to do with the intermingling of the two operations, so I tried setting the transaction propagation to REQUIRE_NEW, but that didn't seem to help.

Any advice? It's the only remaining issue that I have with an otherwise fully functional test case.

PS: Here's the auto-increment code:

```
public void resetAutoIncrement(){
    Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory).getDialect();
    if(dialect instanceof MySQLDialect){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createSQLQuery("alter table student auto_increment = 1")
        .executeUpdate();
    }
    else{
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Method is only compatible with MySQL database");
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the entire test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration ({"classpath:/test-context.xml"})
public class StudentDaoTest extends TestCase{

private static final String INSERT_FAIL = "Insert Failed";
private static final String UPDATE_FAIL = "Update Failed";
private static final String DELETE_FAIL = "Delete Failed";

//TODO document how this class has the Spring dependencies
@Autowired
private StudentDao studentDao;

public StudentDao getStudentDao() {
    return studentDao;
}

public void setStudentDao(StudentDao studentDao) {
    this.studentDao = studentDao;
}

@Transactional
@Test
public void testStudentOperations(){
    Student student = new Student();
    setStudent1(student);
    studentDao.insertStudent(student);
    int studentId = student.getStudentId();

    student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
    assertNotNull(INSERT_FAIL, student);
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getFirstName(), "First");
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getLastName(), "Last");
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getBirthDate(), LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1));
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getGender(), 'U');
    assertEquals(INSERT_FAIL, student.getGrade(), 1);

    setStudent2(student);
    studentDao.updateStudent(student);

    student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
    assertNotNull(UPDATE_FAIL, student);
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getFirstName(), "First2");
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getLastName(), "Last2");
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getBirthDate(), LocalDate.of(1950, 1, 1));
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getGender(), 'M');
    assertEquals(UPDATE_FAIL, student.getGrade(), 2);

    studentDao.deleteStudent(student);

    student = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
    assertNull(DELETE_FAIL, student);
}

private void setStudent1(Student student){
    student.setFirstName("First");
    student.setLastName("Last");
    student.setBirthDate(LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1));
    student.setGender('U');
    student.setGrade(1);
}

private void setStudent2(Student student){
    student.setFirstName("First2");
    student.setLastName("Last2");
    student.setBirthDate(LocalDate.of(1950, 1, 1));
    student.setGender('M');
    student.setGrade(2);
}

@Transactional
@Test
public void testListOperation(){
    Student student = new Student();
    setStudent1(student);
    studentDao.insertStudent(student);

    List<Student> students = studentDao.getAllStudents();
    assertNotNull("Students list is null", students);
    assertTrue("Students list less than 1", students.size() >= 1);
    assertTrue("Students list doesn't contain student", students.contains(student));
}

@Transactional
@After
public void after(){
    System.out.println("Running");
    if(studentDao instanceof HibernateStudentDao){
        System.out.println("Correct Dao");
        ((HibernateStudentDao) studentDao).resetAutoIncrement();
    }
    else{
        throw new RuntimeException("Auto-Increment not reset");
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: The DAO class:

```
public class HibernateStudentDao implements StudentDao {

/**
 * The <tt>SessionFactory</tt> that this class uses
 * for connecting to the database.
 */
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/**
 * Create this DAO with the mandatory <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * that it requires. Passing null as this parameter will
 * cause this class to not be able to function.
 * 
 * @param sessionFactory the <tt>SessionFactory</tt> this class
 * needs to create database sessions.
 */
public HibernateStudentDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * Get the <tt>SessionFactory</tt> used by this class
 * for database sessions.
 * 
 * @return the <tt>SessionFactory used by this class.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 */
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws HibernateException if the database operation fails.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 */
@Override
public void insertStudent(Student student) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(student);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws HibernateException if the database operation fails.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 */
@Override
public void updateStudent(Student student) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(student);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws HibernateException if the database operation fails.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 */
@Override
public Student getStudent(int studentId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (Student) session.createCriteria(Student.class)
                .setFetchMode("courses", FetchMode.JOIN)
                .add(Restrictions.naturalId().set("studentId", studentId))
                .uniqueResult();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws HibernateException if the database operation fails.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //Criteria.list() doesn't support generics
@Override
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return session.createCriteria(Student.class)
            .list();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws HibernateException if the database operation fails.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 */
@Override
public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(student);
}

/**
 * Reset the auto-increment counter on the database table
 * for the <tt>Student</tt> class. This will set the counter
 * generating ids to the next highest number based on the
 * records currently in the table. This is especially useful
 * during testing operations.
 * <p>
 * <b>NOTE:</b> This operation is only compatible with a 
 * MySQL database, as it uses MySQL-specific syntax. Attempting
 * to use it with a different database will cause an exception
 * to be thrown.
 * 
 * @throws HibernateException if the database operation fails.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if this operation is
 * attempted with a database that's not MySQL. 
 */
public void resetAutoIncrement(){
    Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory).getDialect();
    if(dialect instanceof MySQLDialect){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createSQLQuery("alter table student auto_increment = 1")
        .executeUpdate();
    }
    else{
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Method is only compatible with MySQL database");
    }
}

/**
 * Close the <tt>SessionFactory</tt> when this class's work
 * is complete.
 * 
 * @throws HibernateException if the database operation fails.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the <tt>SessionFactory</tt>
 * was set to null.
 */
public void closeSessionFactory(){
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

}

Comment: How is the session factory in your DAO created: injected by Spring, or is it created by your own?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you explicite requested that the After method use an new transaction

```
@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)  <----- that start an new transaction
@After
public void after(){...}
```

Solutions:

you could either:

- use: `Propagation.REQUIRED` instead of `REQUIRES_NEW`
- remove the `@Transactional` annotation (and put one at the Test class)
- maybe: delete the after method at all, because when the test code runs in a transaction that is rolled back (but not committed) then I would expect that the autoincrement values for the next test are not "changed"

I would try solution 3, and if this does not work, I would use the second one:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
//has a own transaction for each test case that will rolled back
public MyTestClass {

   @Before
   public void before() {
       //run within THE transaction
   }

   @After
   public void after() {
       //run within THE transaction
   }

   @Test
   public void myTest() {
       //run within THE same transaction
   }
}
```

Spring Reference http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx

Comment: I added the REQUIRES_NEW after it was already having that result without it. I tried both of your suggestions, neither worked. The thing is, I'm trying to figure out a way to reset the auto increment after the tests. So if I remove the method altogether, how would I accomplish this? I don't want my tests to use up tons of values in my table's key column.

Comment: Then it is maybe that you have a REQUIRES_NEW somewhere else in the code that is invoked by the test

Comment: @user2223059: I would check the DAO. (mybe you post it?)

Comment: Nope. Don't. As I said, I only added REQUIRES_NEW after this problem happened in the first place. I just pasted the full test of this class in my question above. After doing that, I changed it to remove the @Transactional annotations over the individual methods and place it at the top of the class. Still same result.

Comment: @user2223059: you did not post the DAO (or I did not find it)

Comment: Just posted the DAO, my answer was to your previous comment about requires new. I've been trying to see if this is a DB issue, I tried running the exact same sequence natively in an SQL transaction directly in the database. Seems to work perfectly there. Maybe the issue is with Hibernate, and it can't handle an alter table statement in a rollback transaction?